# set icon after input onChange

Tags: angular, icons, mat-input

I want to add icon after input field it will display on change.
and another icon if its not on focus.

Can anyone help me please
i have tried something like below but i don't know how to toggle icon in this.

```
<input matInput type="text" style="width: 200px;">
<button mat-mini-fab  style="float: right;" color="primary" (click)="element.disabled = !element.disabled">
  <mat-icon>{{element.disabled ? 'home' : 'edit'}}</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to you use FormControl to check change and focus ? Check this link for more information : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do it.

in .ts file define two boolean variables.and change value on focus and focus out event of input element.

```
home: boolean = false;
edit:boolean = true;

onFocusOutEvent(event: any){
// toggle as you want to use it.
}
onFocusEvent(){
// toggle as you want to use it.
}
```

in HTML file

```
<input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="element.id" (focusout)="onFocusOutEvent($event)" (focus)="onFocusEvent($event)" >

<button style="float: right;" color="primary" *ngIf="edit">
     <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
<button *ngIf="home" style="float:left;">
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
</button>
```

i hope it's helpful for someone. thank you